# How do I reduce a Clojure sequence in parallell

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

I have an unsorted sequence of maps (TV programs) that I need to merge, meaning that the resulting sequence is unique based on a special key (:title), and the other keys are merged with the duplicates. Think of it as merging all showings of a particular TV show into a single entry that hold all information about them.

A program looks like this (simplified):

```
[{:prog {:title "", ...} :starts #{} :directors #{} :actors #{} :categories {}}, ...]
```

Here's my current function that does the merging:

```
(defn- merge-programs [all-programs]
    "Merge all instances of the same program"
    (loop [acc      []
           programs all-programs]
        (if (empty? programs)
            acc
            (let [first-prog  (first programs)
                  dups        (filter #(= (:title first-prog) (:title (:prog %))) programs)
                  merged-prog {:prog       first-prog
                               :starts     (apply set/union (map :starts     dups))
                               :directors  (apply set/union (map :directors  dups))
                               :actors     (apply set/union (map :actors     dups))
                               :categories (apply set/union (map :categories dups))}]
                (recur (conj acc merged-prog)
                       (remove #(= (:title first-prog) (:title (:prog %)))) programs))))))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this merging in parallel. But since, after each iteration of the loop, "random" elements of the start sequence are being removed, it would have to be some divide-and-conquer approach.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The [Reducers](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html) functionality in Clojure 1.5 is what you want.